# React - wrap multiple elements in parent node

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following array of words that compose some sentences:

```
let words = [
  {
    "start_time": "2.54",
    "end_time": "3.28",
    "alternatives": [
      {
        "confidence": "1.0",
        "content": "Hello",
        "__typename": "Alternative"
      }
    ],
    "type": "pronunciation",
    "__typename": "TranscriptItems"
  },
  {
    "start_time": null,
    "end_time": null,
    "alternatives": [
      {
        "confidence": "0.0",
        "content": ".",
        "__typename": "Alternative"
      }
    ],
    "type": "punctuation",
    "__typename": "TranscriptItems"
  },
  {
    "start_time": "3.29",
    "end_time": "3.52",
    "alternatives": [
      {
        "confidence": "1.0",
        "content": "This",
        "__typename": "Alternative"
      }
    ],
    "type": "pronunciation",
    "__typename": "TranscriptItems"
  }
]
```

Also i have this variable that contain an array of snippets selected from the words above:

```
const snippets = [{ start: 2.54, end: 4.00, id: 12, snippetTitle: "This is the title" }];
```

Right now I am showing the words by doing a simple `.map` and returning `<span>`s for every word.

What I am trying to accomplish is the following: if the span i am currently on is between a snippet from `snippets` variable, wrap it in another div/component so i can highlight it.

So instead of `<span>Hello</span>.<span>This</span>` i would be able to wrap both spans in a new wrapper component or div like `<Highlight><span>Hello</span>.<span>This</span></Highlight>`

Comment: Just add a condition before your return in the .map function?

Comment: Problem is that the highlight might match just a subset of elements in map

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using the reduce function:

```
export default myComponent = () => {
    let cache = [];
    return (
        <>
            {myArray.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
                if(!isInSnippets(currentValue)){
                    if(cache.length > 0){ // return the cached value for highlight
                       accumulator.push( (<Highlight>
                                             {cache.map((elt, i) => <span key={i}>{elt}</span>)
                                          </Highlight>));
                       cache = [];
                    }
                    accumulator.push(<span>{currentValue}</span>);
                }
                else cache.push(currentValue);
                return accumulator;
            }}
        </>
    )
}
```

The accumulator will contain an array of jsx elements. The regular elements will be contained in spans, while the Highlighted elements will be contained all together within a Highlight component.

We store the Highlighted elements in a `cache` variable. When we face a "regular" element, we check if there is something in the cache. If there is, we put them all in a highlight element, and add it to the cache. Then we add the "current" regular value.

Comment: this method works but when trying to make it recursive i get stuck, can't get it to work with nested <highlight>. For example there can be a highlight in a bigger highlight. Any hints on how i can reach that?

Comment: Under what condition would you have nested highlights? Is there a limit to the amount of nested highlights? If yes, you can have several cache variables.

Comment: consider a big snippet between second 1 and 60, so a 59 second snippet. Inside this one i can have another one, between second 10 and 20. Maybe i can limit the amount of depth here but still I need this behaviour to have overlapping regions.

Comment: You could use nested arrays for cache. This would make the checks inside the reduce function a bit more complex but this is the idea. If you don't find a way to do it, I think you should open another question (because this is not the initial question)